# Can the drawable used in SwipeRefreshLayout be changed?

Tags: android, drawable, geometry, android-progressbar, swiperefreshlayout

Is it possible to change the default progress drawable in [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) to a custom drawable?

If yes, will I lost the rotation/animation or other property?

[image: The said drawable]

Comment: The drawable  used in SwipeRefreshLayout is MaterialProgressDrawable (android.support.v4.widget.MaterialProgressDrawable). This is package private class and we cannot use it directly. And the mProgress field of SwipeRefreshLayout is private field and its class type is MaterialProgressDrawable. We cannot change it anyway. You should develop the new class like SwipeRefreshLayout with another drawable.

Answer (score 3):

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_swiperefresh_id);
try {
    Field f = mSwipeRefreshLayout.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCircleView");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    ImageView img = (ImageView)f.get(mSwipeRefreshLayout);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_drawable_file);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: reflection thou :(